# Infinite cardinal comparation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ two infinite cardinal numbers.

**Can we have $\alpha = \beta^\alpha$?**

This problem comes from a situation where I am dealing with the cardinal of a set of functions.

Answer (score 4):

No, we cannot. Cantor's diagonalization argument shows that $\alpha<2^\alpha,$ and it is readily apparent that $2^\alpha\le\beta^\alpha$ for any $\beta\ge 2.$

Comment: In fact, you get that $2^\alpha=\beta^\alpha$ whenever $2\le\beta\le 2^\alpha$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo If α<β is it true: α=β^α?

Comment: @Sushil: No. If $\alpha=0,$ then $\beta^\alpha=1,$ regardless of $\beta,$ so it certainly isn't true there. Otherwise, we have $2\le\beta,$ so $\alpha<\beta^\alpha$ for the reasons described above.